# Cumulative total for quarters

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I currently have a query which produces data for each quarter, what I would like is for the total to be a running total.  So quarter 2's figures will be added on to quarter 1's and so on until the end of the fiscal year, where the process will then start again.

```
select  datepart(year,date) as Year,
    CASE
    WHEN MONTH(date) BETWEEN 1  AND 3  THEN convert(char(4), YEAR(date) - 1) + 'Q4'
    WHEN MONTH(date) BETWEEN 4  AND 6  THEN convert(char(4), YEAR(date) - 0) + 'Q1'
    WHEN MONTH(date) BETWEEN 7  AND 9  THEN convert(char(4), YEAR(date) - 0) + 'Q2'
    WHEN MONTH(date) BETWEEN 10 AND 12 THEN convert(char(4), YEAR(date) - 0) + 'Q3'
END AS Quarter,

 Data1,
 Data2,

FROM TABLE

GROUP BY datepart(year,date),
    CASE
    WHEN MONTH(date) BETWEEN 1  AND 3  THEN convert(char(4), YEAR(date) - 1) + 'Q4'
    WHEN MONTH(date) BETWEEN 4  AND 6  THEN convert(char(4), YEAR(date) - 0) + 'Q1'
    WHEN MONTH(date) BETWEEN 7  AND 9  THEN convert(char(4), YEAR(date) - 0) + 'Q2'
    WHEN MONTH(date) BETWEEN 10 AND 12 THEN convert(char(4), YEAR(date) - 0) + 'Q3'
END
```

This is what I currently get

```
year    quarter     data1        data2

2016      Q1         10            4
2016      Q2         5             6
2016      Q3         4             2
2017      Q4         1             1
```

I would like the output to look like this

```
year    quarter     data1        data2

2016      Q1         10            4
2016      Q2         15            10
2016      Q3         19            12
2017      Q4         20            13
```

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 1):

You can wrap your query in a CTE and use `CROSS APPLY` in order to calculate the cumulative sum:

```
;WITH CTE AS (
   -- your query
)
SELECT t1.year, t1.quarter, t1.data1, t3.cumulative_sum
FROM CTE AS t1 
CROSS APPLY (
   SELECT SUM(data2) AS cumulative_sum
   FROM CTE AS t2
   WHERE t2.year <= t1.year AND t2.quarter <= t1.quarter) AS t3
```

Answer (score 1):

First, your query can be simplified to:

```
SELECT datepart(year, date) as Year,
       datename(year, date) + 'Q' + datename(quarter, dateadd(month, -3, date)) as quarter,
       SUM(Data1) as Data1, SUM(Data2) as Data2
FROM TABLE
GROUP BY datepart(year, date) as Year,
         datename(year, date) + 'Q' + datename(quarter, dateadd(month, -3, date)) as quarter
ORDER BY quarter;
```

Note the use of `datename()`.  This returns a string rather than a number, which is easier for string concatenation.  In addition, this simplifies the logic just by subtracting 3 months to get the quarter.

In SQL Server 2012+, you can use the built in functionality for cumulative sum.  In SQL Server 2008, one method uses `apply`:

```
WITH t as (
      SELECT datepart(year, date) as Year,
             datename(year, date) + 'Q' + datename(quarter, dateadd(month, -3, date)) as quarter,
             SUM(Data1) as Data1, SUM(Data2) as Data2
      FROM TABLE
      GROUP BY datepart(year, date) as Year,
               datename(year, date) + 'Q' + datename(quarter, dateadd(month, -3, date)) as quarter
     )
SELECT t.*, tt.data2
FROM t OUTER APPLY
     (SELECT SUM(data1) as data2
      FROM t t2
      WHERE t2.quarter <= t.quarter
     ) tt;
```

Comment: I think you miss the aggregation for Data1, Data2 ? And not sure why you didnt use window function instead

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza . . . Because you asked.  There were several things to fix in the query (the quarter calculation and the `apply`).  I simply wasn't focused on the actual aggregation of the data.